# How to return the promise then()/catch() result to the function containing the promise?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my situation I am working with auth guard `CanActivate()` restricting the user access for every route, however the condition value is taken from http request Promise object. How can i access the Promise then() and catch() and return it to `CanActivate(): Boolean` function?

My code look something like this.

```
// On AuthService
verfifyUser(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http
      .get(`api/auth/verify-user`, { headers: this.headers })
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => res.json() as any);
}


// On AuthGuardService
CanActivate(): Boolean {
    this.authSrv.verfifyUser(some_user).then(result => {
         // return true
    }).catch(err => {
         // return false 
    });
}
```

I still can't figure out how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return type of `canActivate` method of the [**CanActivate**](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) interface is `Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean`.

You can use `canActivate(): Promise<boolean>` version and return a Promise. In the function you can write

```
canActivate() : Promise<boolean> {

   return new Promise( resolve => {

      this.authSrv.verfifyUser(some_user).then(result => {
         resolve(true);
      }).catch(err => {
         resolve(false);
      });

   });

}
```

Comment: Hi there i will try this one but just curious of the outcome it is still valid to use this on ` {  path: 'some-path/',  component: ClientComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]  }`?

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab Yes of course, it is one variant of the `canActivate` function